# Spring REST HATEOAS

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-hateoas

I am trying to follow best practices imagine a basic API with /books endpoint.

I've the following classes:
Book
BookRepository (PagingAndSortingRepository but not exported!!)
BookController (this is the serving class)
BookResource ("representation" of the book in "REpresentational State Transfer")
BookResourceAssembler

My BookController looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getBook(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Book book = bookRepository.findOne(id);
        BookResource bookResource = this.bookResourceAssembler.toResource(book);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(bookResource);
    }
```

my BookResource looks like this:

```
public class BookResource extends ResourceSupport{
    public String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

BookResourceAssembler:

```
@Component
public class BookResourceAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<Book, BookResource> {

      public BookResourceAssembler() {
        super(BookController.class, BookResource.class);
      }


    @Override
    public BookResource toResource(Book entity) {
        BookResource resource = createResourceWithId(entity.getDbid(), entity);
        return resource;
    }
}
```

My first problem is easy one to solve I guess, title is not initialized so when I call /books/1 I get title: null.

Second and more important question is how do I do content-negotiation and versioning, which is a really important aspect of RESTful API. How should I introduce BookResourceV2 and where should I negotiate it? Let's say I want

```
"Content-Type: application/vnd.company.book+json.v2"
```

where do I state this? Which new classes/functions should I add to handle this v2 of the same resource?

I couldn't find a good tutorial that covers all aspects.

Answer (score 0):

> My first problem is easy one to solve I guess, title is not
>   initialized so when I call /books/1 I get title: null.

You're using BookResource the wrong way.
I assume your domain object (Book) looks something like:

```
public class Book {
    public String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

BookResource is a wrapper that adds links to the domain object and present it in a RESTful way...

```
public class BookResource extends Resource<Book> {

    public BookResource(Book content, Link... links) {
        super(content, links);
    }

}
```

For the record, in this case you don't even need custom Resource and ResourceAssembler classes:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getBook(@PathVariable Long id,
    PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {
    Book book = bookRepository.findOne(id);
    if (null == book) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(assembler.toResource(book));
}
```

In this very simple case (no special processing of the Book instance), you wouldn't even need this endpoint, since Spring generates it for you.

> Second and more important question is how do I do content-negotiation
>   and versioning, which is a really important aspect of RESTful API. How
>   should I introduce BookResourceV2 and where should I negotiate it?

You need to define a `RepositoryRestController` and use the `produces` parameter of your `RequestMapping`-annotated controller endpoints, similarly to what I explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43092913/5873923).